i can not run the code after update to sdk51
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Test_code\InternalBytecode.js'
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:20)
at getCodeFrame (C:\Users\ADMIN\Test_code\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:868:18)
at Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\ADMIN\Test_code\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:945:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at Server._processRequest (C:\Users\ADMIN\Test_code\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:394:7) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Test_code\InternalBytecode.js'
}
How to fix this error ?
i tried to update from sdk 50 to sdk51 and it happened
